# How to check two if condition in angular unit testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have a method showStatus() in my ts file and in if loop two conditions must satisfy, but I'm not able to figure out how to write this condition in test cases.

**.ts**

```
public showStatus(str:Event)
{
 if(this.currUser != null && this.statusValid.valid) 
 {
 const status = new Status();
 status.statustext = this.statusValid.value;
 status.name = this.currUser.username;
 
 if(str.statuses == null){
 event.statuses = new Statuses();
 }

 str.statuses.allstatus.push(status);
 }
```

**test cases**

```
it('should validate', () => {
spyOn(obj, 'showStatus').and.returnValue(true);
component.showStatus(mockdata)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In what you shared I see you are not validating rather than sanitizing. Then this changes what you should be focusing on.

This function is modifying `mockdata` in place, so you should focus on checking `mockdata.statuses.allstatus` is valid after calling the function.

Let's say a status is a string that should only contains A-Z characters:

```
it('should sanitize', () => {
 // given
 const invalidStatus = "_DELIVERED_";
 mockdata.statuses.allstatus = [invalidStatus];

 // when
 component.showStatus(mockdata);

 // then
 const expectedStatus = "DELIVERED"; 
 expect(mockdata.statuses.allstatus).toContain(expected);

});
```

I hope this helps.